# Reading a UTF-16 CSV file by char

Tags: c, csv, ascii, utf-16

Currently I am trying to read a UTF-16 encoded CSV file char by char, and convert each char into ascii so I can process it. I later plan to change my processed data back to UTF-16 but that is besides the point right now.

I know right off the bat I am doing this completely wrong, as I have never attempted anything like this before:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    if(!(fp = fopen("x.csv", "r"))) return 1;
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
                ch = (wchar_t) ch;
                ch = (char) ch;
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Wishfully thinking, I was hoping that that work by magic for some reason but that was not the case. How can I read a UTF-16 CSV file and convert it to ascii? My guess is since each utf-16 char is two bytes (i think?) I'm going to have to read two bytes at a time from the file into a variable of some datatype which I am not sure of. Then I guess I will have to check the bits of this variable to make sure it is valid ascii and convert it from there? I don't know how I would do this though and any help would be great.

Comment: Does the CSV file only contain characters that exist in ASCII?

Comment: Yes which is the nice part, it's only UTF-16 encoded because of the software that generated it (WonderWare)

Comment: you should be able to read only every 2nd byte to get the desired result. the other byte should then always be zero.

Comment: every second byte hm? so then would writing it back to utf-16 (assuming the characters being used are still all ASCII chars) I would make every first byte null?

Comment: @KeithMiller yes, though take care of your handling of the BOM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Thank you so much all of you! Now my task is easy as `if(i % 2)` and `if(!(i % 2))` you guys are awesome! thanks again!

Comment: Well, honestly, one should not be having a UTF-16 CSV file unless he really knows what he is doing.

Comment: Yeah in an ideal world :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`fgetwc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetwc). The below code should work in the presence of a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and an available locale named `en_US.UTF-16`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-16"); 

  FILE *fp = fopen("x.csv", "rb");
  if (fp) {
    int order = fgetc(fp) == 0xFE;
    order = fgetc(fp) == 0xFF;

    wint_t ch;
    while ((ch = fgetwc(fp)) != WEOF) {
      putchar(order ? ch >> 8 : ch);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
  } else {
    perror("opening x.csv");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: @oldrinb I setlocale needed?

Comment: @user877329 to ensure `fgetwc` does what we want it to, yes

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution thanks to the comments under my original question. Since every character in the CSV file is valid ascii the solution was simple as this:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ch, i = 1;
    if(!(fp = fopen("x.csv", "r"))) return 1;
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(i % 2) //ch is valid ascii
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```