# read 2 bytes in from a .txt file

Tags: c, fread, utf-16

I'm reading a file in c and I'm trying to read it as one UTF-16 character at a time from a text file, which is 2 bytes. I'm pretty rusty, but here is what I have:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen( "myfile.txt" , 'r' );

size_t readIn;
size_t* readp = &readIn;

fread( readp , 2 , 1 , fp );
```

This feels wrong to me somehow, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `size_t* readp = &readIn;` is unnecessary. `fread( &readIn, 2 , 1 , fp );` would work the same. Other than that, perhaps `uint16_t` would be a more suitable type for `readIn`.

Comment: What makes you think that a size_t is the right type of object to hold a UTF_16 character. Here's an example of how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125659/reading-a-utf-16-csv-file-by-char

Comment: You should declare `readIn` to be of a type that is two bytes long (usually `short int`). Otherwise it looks OK. Of course you may have to worry about endianness too...

Comment: If it really is UTF_16 but you don't have a UTF_16 library to read such files, then you might need to open it binary.

Comment: Please do open it in binary, which is generally what you should do when using fread anyway. Use "rb" instead of "r" (note the double quotes; single quotes are only for single characters while double quotes are for strings).

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use :

```
unsigned char readp[2];
while((fread(readp,2,1,fp) == 1) {

}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point...? Reading a UTF-16 file requires reading the first two bytes only to determine the byte order of the text, assuming it hasn't already been established by other means (e.g. an HTTP header). After that, yes, you can read character by character, except in the case of UTF-16 surrogate pairs. However, those could be handled by an extra fread call in the loop to get the next two bytes (the other half of the surrogate pair).